# how to change max length of linebreak in android studio IDE?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

As you can see, the IDE linebreak is really small for me and when using auto - indent it will refactor it to a really small size

How do I change the settings so that the IDE will move that grey line further up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution -

[image]

change the value from 100 to whatever you want, I changed to 500